# How to convert check name attribute value as array

Tags: jquery, html

I have check box has like below. I am not able to edit the below code because below code generate dynamically.

```
<input onclick="ToggleButtonBaseComponent.prototype.callAjaxAfterRender(&quot;render_se
ctor_name&quot;)" type="checkbox" class="render_sector_name"
 name="render_sector_name" value="C&amp;D_Europa_Joan_Güell2" checked="checked">
```

What i want is just convert name="render_sector_name" to name="render_sector_name[]". By using jquery.

**expecting result:-**

```
    <input onclick="ToggleButtonBaseComponent.prototype.callAjaxAfterRender(&quot;render_se
ctor_name&quot;)" type="checkbox" class="render_sector_name" 
name="render_sector_name[]" value="C&amp;D_Europa_Joan_Güell2" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is change the attributes of a DOM object.

You can alter any `attr` by using the following convention (name, etc).

```
$(function(){
    $('.render_sector_name').attr('name', 'render_sector_name[]');
});
```

Feel free to see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fe0y5f1p/

Comment: hi, not one checkbox it is multiple checkboxes how to loop?

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka the selector `$('.render_sector_name')` will match all elements with the class `render_sector_name`. ie, this WILL change all of the boxes the loop is handled internally by jQuery

Comment: If this answered your question properly please select the green checkbox next to the answer title.